# Text Loop on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to animate text in react native and keep it in a loop. I was able to find a reactjs package that achieves this (react-text-loop), but could not find one for react native. Does anyone know how this can be achieved, below is a sample gif of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Animated or LayoutAnimation api. Check the [Official Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations)